# How do I instantiate a Scala case class using all the attributes of a smaller case class?

Tags: scala, class, instantiation

I have an instance of a case class A:

```
case class A(
  foo: String,
  bar: String,
  baz: String
)
val a = A("a", "b", "c")
```

I want to use this to create an instance of a case class B, with attributes that are a superset of A:

```
case class B(
  foo: String,
  bar: String,
  baz: String,
  qux: String,
  quux: String
)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this than `val b = (A.foo, A.bar, A.baz, "d", "e")` ? I have to do this a few times in my code, and my actual use case has something like 20 parameters, so doing it the obvious way is very long-winded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, a `case class` with 20 parameters is usually a sign of bad design, so think about grouping those parameters into smaller classes and then putting them together in a container class.

If you keep this design and don't want to use external libraries, you can make a constructor for `B` that takes `A` plus the extra parameters:

```
object B {
  def apply(a: A, qux: String, quux: String): B = B(a.foo, a.bar, a.baz, qux, quux)
}

val a:A = ???
val b = B(a, "qux", "quux")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define one or more implicit conversions.

```
implicit class A2B(a:A) {
  def toB(x:String, y:String) :B = B(a.foo,a.bar,a.baz,x,y)
  //other conversion methods here
}

val a = A("a", "b", "c")  //a: A = A(a,b,c)
val b = a.toB("d", "e")   //b: B = B(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [henkan](https://github.com/kailuowang/henkan) does exactly what you want.

```
import henkan.convert.Syntax._

val b:B = A("a", "b", "c").to[B].set(qux = "d", quux = "e")
```

Henkan uses shapeless under the hood, so you could also use it to write your own solutions.